# RabbitMQ management plugin windows renders as blank page

Tags: javascript, windows, rabbitmq

I have installed Erlang, RabbitMQ and configured the management plugin as per the instructions on the [website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) and restarted the RabbitMQ service. But when I navigate to http://localhost:15672/ I see a blank page, although the page source looks <del>potentially ok</del> identical to that which I see when browsing other RabbitMQ servers on our network:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RabbitMQ Management</title>
    <script src="js/ejs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot.time.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/sammy-0.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/prefs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/help.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/formatters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/charts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="js/excanvas.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/evil.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="outer"></div>
    <div id="debug"></div>
    <div id="scratch"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am running IE 11 in a corporate environment, so wondering if it is some kind of security weirdness preventing the JavaScript from running, although "localhost" is zoned as local intranet, "medium-low" security, so should be fine? I don't have this issue trying to browse to RabbitMQ management page on any of our servers, just on localhost.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use a fqdn ? Any messages in F12 ? Are the http headers different ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think is this issue: 
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/98

It is a new issue introducted on the version 3.6.0.

You can try using Firefox or Chrome.

If you are using another version try to clear the cache, if still persist check the error console.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the issue. I have located an old version of Firefox portable and it shows the same error.