# RabbitMQ - Cannot access management http api

Tags: rabbitmq

I installed RabbitMQ V3.6.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2. The RabbitMQ is running and is OK. I can access the queues. 
I can even access the **http://localhost:15672/api/** page.
But when I request **http://localhost:15672/** I get an empty page. I don't see the login form.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks, Hakan

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613120/rabbitmq-management-plugin-windows-renders-as-blank-page

Comment: Yes, it is the same issue. When I request the page in Chrome it is displayed. Thank you.

Comment: It will be fixed to the version 3.6.1!